# Cannot invoke my method on the array type int[]

Tags: java, object, methods

I'm currently learning how to use genetic algorithms. However, I'm having difficulty with my method `compareTo()`. This method should compare the fitness values between two individuals. I've been trying to invoke my `getFitness()` method for it to be used in the `compareTo()` method, but I keep getting this error

> Cannot invoke getFitness() on the array type int[]

I'm not sure where this error is coming from. Attached will be the mentioned methods and constructors, I will outline where this error occurs. Thank you.

```java
public class Individual implements Comparable<Individual> {
  Random rand=new Random(); //Initialize random object
  private int size; //Represents N queens
  private int[] individual; //Represents the array of possible solutions

  public Individual(int[] permutation) {
    individual=permutation;
    size=individual.length;
  }

  public Individual(int size) {
    this.size=size;
    individual=Util.getPermutation(size); //Constructs an individual object that is an array of ints
  }

  public int getFitness() {
    //How many queens are attacking each other on the diagonal
    // 0 Represents the best fitness, this is the solution

    //Number of possible differences in permutation is found through factorial addition
    int newSize=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=size; i++){
      newSize+=i;
    }
    int fitness=0;
    int [] xDifference=new int[newSize]; //Array that stores distance between Columns
    int [] yDifference=new int[newSize]; //Array that stores distance between rows

    //Calculates the distance between columns and stores them
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
      for (int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
        xDifference[i]=j-i;
    }

    //Calculates distance between rows and stores them
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
      for (int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
          yDifference[i]=Math.abs(individual[j]-individual[i]);
    }

    //Compares xDifference and yDifference elements, if they are equal that means Queens are attacking
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
      if (xDifference[i]==yDifference[i]){
        fitness++;
      }
    }

    return fitness;
  }

  public int compareTo(Individual other) {
    int compare;

    if (individual.getFitness()<other.getFitness()){ //ERROR OCCURS HERE
      compare=-1;
    }else if (individual.getFitness()>other.getFitness()){// ERROR HERE
      compare=1;
    }else {
      compare=0;
    }

    return compare;
  }
}
```

Comment: `individual` is your `array of possible solutions` and it is an `int[]`. You want to use `this` instead of `individual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `individual.getFitness()`. `individual` is indeed an `int[]`, not an `Individual` object. Instead, you'll want to use

```
if (this.getFitness()<other.getFitness()){ 
     compare=-1;
}
```

You could also leave out `this.`, but I personally find that it makes code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

In your compareTo method you are accessing the field `individual` which is an array, not an `Individual`.