# Cannot invoke method on the array type int[]

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class listed as such:

```
public class Something {

private int foo;
private int bar;
private int [] array = new int [16];

public Something()
    {
    foo = 0;
    bar = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
        array[i] = 0;   
        }
    }
```

I want to break the array iteration into a separate method so I can reuse or re-invoke it throughout my program something like this:

```
public void arrayItteration(){
    for (int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;   
    }
}
```

Then I want to call it inside my public method such as:

```
public Something()
    {
    foo = 0;
    bar = 0;
    int [] arrayOp = array.arrayItteration();
    }
```

Ive tried the solution here: [Cannot invoke my method on the array type int[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398843/cannot-invoke-my-method-on-the-array-type-int) by adding `this.` but its still not working. I have my setters and getters for all available variables.  Im sure theres an easy fix to this but please let me know if theres a way around it.

Thank you

Comment: [`Arrays.fill(array, 0);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing a few wrong things here:

1. calling a custom method `arrayItteration` on a regular `int[]`-array
2. trying to assign the `void` return value to *anything*
3. you needlessly try to get a reference to the some class member

---

Simplest fix:

1. simply call the method
2. do not assign the return value
3. do not introduce a new local variable

That yields:

```
public Something() {
    foo = 0;
    bar = 0;
    arrayItteration();
}
```

Comment: gahhh....knew it would be that easy.  Thanks I come from a Ruby background im used to assigning a reference to everything.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3670893 you *could* create a method, that *returns* a *new* initialized array and assign that return value to `array`. But if your method is `void` you cannot even assign the return value to anything.